# What is the best way to handle boolean bounds with scipy's minimize function?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to find the minimum value of a function that takes `float` and `bool` values as input.

```py
def function_to_optimize(a : float, b : float, c : bool) -> float:
    # do some calculation...
```

How do I define the `bounds` parameter of the `scipy.optimize.minimize` regarding my `bool` variable `c`?

Say that the bounds for `a` and `b` are `(0,1)`. What I am doing currently is to modify `function_to_optimize` so that it takes 3 `float` parameters and doing the following:

```py
def new_function_to_optimize(a : float, b : float, c : float) -> float:
    c = False if c < 0 else True
    # do some calculation...
```

Then, I apply the bounds as `bounds = [(0,1), (0,1), (-1,1)]`. This way, for variable `c`, when the optimizer tries a value below 0, then c is assigned the value `False` and `True` otherwise.

But I am not sure if this is the best way to do this and if maybe the algorithms behind `minimize` can do some further optimization if he is aware that the variables are of type `bool`. Should I instead define the `bounds` as `(False, True)`?

Comment: Short comment. I tried using bounds with `bool`s like `(False, True)` and it wasn't working. Meaning, the function wasn't being optimized (I was able to find better minima manually). But, when I set the method to `method='Nelder-Mead'`, then it works and a minima is found (better than mine :D). Would this be dependent on the method being applied?

Comment: Depending on your calculations with `c`, your objective function might violate the mathematical assumptions of most of minimize's methods, so it's a bit difficult to help properly without knowing the whole function. Could you please provide the whole function?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the whole function. What I can say though is that this `bool` variable enables/disables certain limits within the function. Not sure if that would help much. Furthermore, I could add that this function to be optimized has a good degree of non-linearity (mostly caused by this switching on/off the limiting function).

Comment: This leads me to believe that it could be better for me to just simply run two optimizations. One with the variable equal to `True` and another with the variable equal to `False` and then manually compare the results...

Comment: Yeah, simply running two optimizations is probably the easiest approach in your case.